# Finding support of each word using python in text data

Tags: python, data-mining

In Python how do find the count of each distinct words from the dataset : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ADdzZp31SwiF70IZ13hbAtPNHBv5NmOY

I already imported the dataset using :

```
# Load the data
fin = open("b.txt", 'r')
translist = []
for line in fin:
    trans = line.strip().split(' ')
    translist.append(trans)
```

I need the support of each element to perform contiguous pattern mining.For example, suppose the phrase "parking lot" has an absolute support 133, then the line corresponding to this frequent contiguous sequential pattern in "b.txt" should be:

133:parking;lot

Comment: Please try out the solution. It has been updated to check for multi word phrases. Phrase length can be set.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. The maximum length phrase sampled for the dictionary is variable p_length (I set 3), the maximum length phrase sampled for the ranking list is p_size (I set 3, the smaller this is, the higher the top frequencies of course), and the number of words in the final ranking list is variable rank (I set 25). These are set on lines 8-10. The length of ranking list that it prints (see near end of 'def top_list():'), is the total number of phrases up to p_length in number of words.

```
# Load the data
fin = open("b.txt", 'r')
translist = []
for line in fin:
    trans = line.strip().split(' ')
    translist.extend(trans)

p_length = 3
p_size = 3
rank = 25

#Use a dictionary to create a histogram1 of the frequencies of the phrases (but this list is not in order)
def histogram1(translist,p_length):
    global dict1
    dict1 = dict()
    phraseList = []
    for transIndex in range(len(translist)):
        for i in range(p_length):
            if (transIndex+1+i) <= len(translist):
                phraseElementNow = translist[transIndex+i]
            else:
                continue
            if i > 0:
                joinables = (newElement, phraseElementNow)
                newElement = ' '.join(joinables)
            else:
                newElement = phraseElementNow
            phraseList.append(newElement)
    for element2 in phraseList:
        if element2 not in dict1:
            dict1[element2] = 1
        else:
            dict1[element2] += 1
    return dict1

#Create the ranked list of phrases vs their frequency.
def top_list():
    global topList
    topList = []
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        topList.append((value, key))
    topList.sort(reverse = True)
    print("Length of ranking list is: ") #Just a check
    print(len(topList))
    #print(topList[-(rank):])   Used this to check format of ranking list

#Choose the top x ranking to print (I made it 25 on line 9).
def short_list(p_size, rank):
    topTopList = []
    print("The "+str(rank)+" most common phrases "+str(p_size)+" words long are: ")
    for phrase in topList:
        phraseParts = phrase[1].split(' ')
        if len(phraseParts) == p_size:
            topTopList.append(phrase)
        else:
            continue
    for freq, word in topTopList[:rank]:
        wordParts = word.split(' ')
        wordForPrint = ';'.join(wordParts)
        completePrint = str(freq)+':'+wordForPrint
        print(completePrint)

print(histogram1(translist, p_length))
top_list()
short_list(p_size, rank)
```